# Powershell .value vs .values

Tags: powershell, dictionary

I have a script that returns a DictionaryEntry collection, I've noticed if that dict happens to only have one K/V pair that I must specify var.value vs if it has multiple its var.values ! what gives? is there a common way to resolve this? in one command?

Comment: Are you using [tag:powergui] by any chance? [See this comment](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36090764/powershell-hash-table-storing-values-of-system-collections-dictionaryentry#comment59826420_36090764).

Comment: hmm no using vscode

Comment: It might be helpful to see your script code, or at least a [mcve]. It sounds to me like when you have multiple entries you're returning a real `[hashtable]` and when you have one, you are for some reason returning a `DictionaryEntry`.

Comment: An individual `DictionaryEntry` has `Key` and `Value` properties. A `Hashtable`, by way of implementing [`IDictionary` interface](https://docs.microsoft.com/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary), has `Keys` and `Values` properties that return all keys and all values, respectively. It sounds like [how properties are handled for collections](https://docs.microsoft.com/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_properties#properties-of-scalar-objects-and-collections) is what you're seeing, though it seems like when you access the single entry it must not be through a collection.

Comment: Though it yielded a quality answer, this question leaves a lot to be desired.  I'd recommend _showing_ rather than (barely) _describing_ the code as well as not relying on abbreviations.

Answer (score 6):

> if that dict happens to only have one K/V pair that I must specify var`.value`

No: The implication is that you're dealing with an *isolated key-value pair* or a (non-dictionary) *collection* (array) of such pairs, such as [`[System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.DictionaryEntry) instances, that *aren't part of a (single) dictionary (hashtable*):

```sh
# Single key-value pair
$kvPair = [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]::new('foo', 42)
$kvPair.Value # -> 42

# Array of key-value pairs
(
  [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]::new('foo', 42), 
  [System.Collections.DictionaryEntry]::new('bar', 43)
).Value # -> 42, 43
```

The fact that [`.Value`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.dictionaryentry.value) works even on an (array-like) *collection* of key-value pairs - even though `.Value` is a property of that collection's *individual elements* - is owed to PowerShell's [member-access enumeration](https://stackoverflow.com/a/44620191/45375) feature.

---

By contrast, [`.Values`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.values) is a type-native property of a *dictionary (hashtable) object*. Such an object contains a (typically unordered) *internal* collection of key-value pairs with distinct keys, whose values the `.Values` property returns as a collection; using a [`[hashtable]`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-US/dotnet/api/System.Collections.Hashtable) literal as an example:

```sh
# Single-entry hashtable.
@{ foo = 42 }.Values # -> @(42) (single-element collection)

# Multi-entry hashtable.
@{ foo = 42; bar = 43 }.Values # -> 42, 43
```

Note, however, that - unlike with member-access enumeration - the `.Values` property *always* returns a *collection*, even if that collection happens to contain just *one* element.

PowerShell considers a dictionary / hashtable a *single object*, which has two implications:

- It is sent *as whole* to the pipeline.

  - To request sending its *entries* (key-value pairs), one by one, instead, you must call `.GetEnumerator()` explicitly.
- Member-access enumeration is *not* applied, so that `.Value` can *not* be used to return the individual entries' `.Value` property values.

  - Instead, use the type-native `.Values` property, as shown above (or [`.Keys`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.collections.idictionary.keys), to get the collection of keys).